# Cannot access django-admin panel on port

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-settings

## Expecting to be able to access django admin panel and add social accouunt

opening admin panel by adding standard `admin/` extension to local preview port URL. This is expected to lead to classic [django admin panel.](https://www.programink.com/static/img/django-admin-login.png)

**going to the admin url instead leads to an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4v0U.png)**

the website is otherwise displaying fine.

*A simple google oath signin is currently being implemented.*

### Error message:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://8000-lmcrean-project4-avaw7dd1zq8.ws-eu106.gitpod.io/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 3.2.23
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py, line 435, in get
Python Executable:  /home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.9.17
Python Path:    
['/workspace/Project-4',
 '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/lib/python39.zip',
 '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/lib/python3.9',
 '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/home/gitpod/.pyenv/versions/3.9.17/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 11 Nov 2023 15:17:58 +0000
```

[traceback details in full](https://file.io/haymHM3ANkEI)

## Currently trying to fix with this tutorial

“Set up Google Sign-in for Faster Django Login Experience Feat. Tech with Tim.” Akamai DevRel, YouTube Video, 12 Dec. 2022, https://youtu.be/yO6PP0vEOMc?feature=shared&t=1328. Accessed 11 Nov. 2023.

- have followed correctly with all working up to 22 minutes in
- migration was recently made after setting up urls, views and templates for google oauth as per the tutorial, there were no obvious issues with this
- before that django-admin panel seemed to be working fine

## settings.py and url are likely problem areas

installed apps seems ok on [settings.py - can be viewed here in full](https://file.io/HDZjRjk17k3w)

this was recently implemented but is correct according to tutorial:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```

urlpatterns in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("blog.urls"), name="blog-urls"),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    path("", include("users.urls"))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Site matching query does not exist," typically occurs in Django when the SITE_ID setting in settings.py refers to a Site object that does not exist in the database.

I managed to debug this with the Python Shell by checking existing site ID.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
existing_site = Site.objects.get(domain='http://127.0.0.1:8000')
print(existing_site.id)
```

The returning statement revealed that the SITE_ID should be 2, not 1 as previously set.

This was fixed with an update to settings.py to match the correct site ID:

```
SITE_ID = 2
```

[The django admin panel can now be accessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY9LK.png) without any further errors.